# who defined the CLICOLOR_FORCE?

Tags: shell, autoconf

who defined the CLICOLOR_FORCE? and which software define the macro originally?
why every configure file from autoconf need these lines:

```
# Unset more variables known to interfere with behavior of common tools.
CLICOLOR_FORCE= GREP_OPTIONS=
unset CLICOLOR_FORCE GREP_OPTIONS
```

searched on Google and Stackoverflow, but there is no answer about that?

Comment: `searched on Google` https://bixense.com/clicolors/

Answer (score 0):

There is a [page](https://bixense.com/clicolors/) about this. As the author [mentioned](https://github.com/chalk/supports-color/issues/32#issuecomment-143028437), it is an OSX thing. AFAIK both `CLICOLOR` and `CLICOLOR_FORCE` were introduced by [FreeBSD 4.1.1-RELEASE](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+4.1.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) around [2000](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/commit/?id=3d2ddc9e1a6a60d585b7c0a3e378b6ef986dac57).